# Not updating the data after the first change

Tags: excel, vba

This creates a function, which I can access by `=Timestamp(G2)`.

"G2" is the cell, when it changes, the date changes. It gets updated every time.

```vb
Function Timestamp(Reference As Range)
If Reference.Value <> "" Then
    Timestamp = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")
Else
    Timestamp = ""
End If
End Function
```

I need to have it stay like it was when the cell changed for the first time.

Comment: The text of your question has little to do with the posted code. Why don't you share the code in which you call this procedure?

Comment: Do you use the above function as UDF? It will get updated each time `Calculate` event is triggered. In order to remain the same time stamp you should call the function by sheet `Change` event and affect the `Target` (changed cell). Which can be limited to a specific range (columns, rows...).

Comment: @VBasic2008 yea, I just realised... I rewrote it, because I was mixing it up with something I  tried something different before.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing logging with the calculation process. IMO this is a bad practice. Of course, we can try some tricks to stop recalculation. But the approach itself is problematic.
I think it would be better to explicitly deal with this as an event logging task. Namely, I would add something like this to the `Worksheet_Change` event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Const WatchTarget = "A1"
Const LogDestination = "B1"
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(WatchTarget)) Is Nothing Then
        ' if no changes were observed before and something significant appeared
        If IsEmpty(Range(LogDestination)) And Len(Range(WatchTarget)) > 0 Then
            ' then save the time when it happened
            Range(LogDestination) = Now
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

p.s. See [the video about the Worksheet Change Event](https://youtu.be/TYyPrqqFgVg)

Comment: Hi, so I copyd it into VBA (had to add a ")" in line 6), but nothing happens when I change any value. What is this code supposed to do, and how is izt supposed to work?

Comment: @Elias Watch this https://youtu.be/TYyPrqqFgVg